# Camera is detected in one USB port but not another

Tags: camera

I'm not certain which forum to post this question in. Please let me know if this is the wrong one!

I have a Logitech c922 pro stream webcam which connects to 2 of my Windows PC's usb ports but not the other. I get the error "Device Descriptor Request Failed" on the third port.
But every other device I have connects to the third port including my ZED stereo camera.

What could the issue be? I see the same issue happening on my lab CPU (ubuntu) as well.

Thanks!